# Using iterator to print a multimap

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

Say I have some

```
    typedef std::pair<userObject*,char> Bar;
    std::multimap<int, Bar > Foo;
    std::multimap<int, Bar >::iterator it = foo.begin();
```

I have inserted a few members into the map and would like to iterate over its content using the iterator.  However, attempting the second line code yields a `no viable conversion from....`

I know the error is caused by `Bar` being a pair.  I have written a simple class using `ints` to simulate the behavior and everything works as expected.  Do I need to provide some template class T? to define the behavior.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/Deverick-Simpson/Schoolworkspace/blob/master/RegDFA/src/GraphTable.cpp) to the source code to see the code.

Error message is

```
    no viable conversion from '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type<int *, [...]>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<int *, std::__1::pair<Vertex *, char> >, void *> *, [...]>>' to '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator<__value_type<int, [...]>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<int, std::__1::pair<Vertex *, char> >, void *> *, [...]>>'
```

Comment: `foo.begin` (no parethesis) - is it a typo or real code?

Comment: This was actually a typo, thanks!

Comment: Please prepare a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code sample you have posted here compiles just fine, provided you change `Foo` to `foo`, which is just a typo. The code on Github is not complete and we can't compile it.

Comment: Will do!  I'm actually working on a more complete edit now.  After abstraction I'm noticing this is not the true cause of my error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not beacuse it is a pair. This is because you are not calling the function foo.begin, but instead trying to take it access it directly.

The proper code is `std::multimap<int, Bar >::iterator it = foo.begin();`

Comment: The proper code is `auto it = std::begin(foo);`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, disagree completely. There is no need to use auto in this example.

Comment: there's probably never a "need" for `auto`.  But regardless, focus on the rvalue, that's LRIO's point.

Comment: @SergeyA: This is _the_ canonical use case for `auto`. No, of course you don't "need" it...

Comment: This does not actually solve the problem.  The missing parenthesis from `foo.begin()` was a typo.  Is there another reason the iterator may be throwing a `no viable conversion from..` error.  Appreciate the help.  I also provided a link to the source code on github.

Comment: @Dev, provide the full code, include the line where the error is printed and provide full error description.

Comment: @BrianCain, of course, there is a need for auto. Lambdas have unknown type. Return value of functions is better expressed with auto. Other cases as well. But iterators? Why would they be auto?

Comment: @SergeyA simply for convenience. It's faster to type, it prevents errors (like using `map` instead of `multimap`), and if you change the type of `Foo` you don't have to adjust all the iterators that work with it, because it's managed *automatically*.